# Open GitHub Issues and Pull Request on behalf of organization

Tags: github

Any idea is it possible to open Issues and submit PRs in GitHub on behalf of organization.

I would like to open an Issue and PR that would say `opened by <orgname>`.
Currently it says `opened by <person>`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible.

Even if you make a comments from a normal GitHub user account, and then convert that user account to a GitHub Organization account, all of your existing comments/commits will no longer be associated with that account:

> - Any commits made with the converted personal account will no longer be linked to that account. The commits themselves will remain intact.
> - Any existing comments made by the converted personal account will no longer be linked to that account. The comments themselves will remain intact, but will be associated with the ghost user.
>
> *Taken from https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-personal-account/converting-a-user-into-an-organization*

**However, GitHub does have a public beta that allows you to document that you made a commit on behalf of an organization account**. Similarly to how you can write [`co-authored-by: NAME <NAME@EMAIL.EXAMPLE>` at the end of your git commit message](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors), you can also write `on-behalf-of: @ORG NAME@ORGANIZATION.COM`.

However, GitHub only registers it if you follow the following strict instructions:

> - you must be a member of the organization indicated in the trailer
> - you must sign the commit
> - your commit email and the organization email must be in a domain verified by the organization
>
> *Taken from https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/creating-a-commit-on-behalf-of-an-organization*

For more info, see the [Creating a commit on behalf of an organization GitHub Docs page](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/creating-a-commit-on-behalf-of-an-organization) or the [Creating a commit on behalf of an organization GitHub Blog post](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-03-15-creating-a-commit-on-behalf-of-an-organization/).